# Drupal 7 Ajax Forms

Tags: ajax, forms, drupal, rendering, drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7, and I am building a web site, that has a contact form in the footer which should appear in every page. The requirements was to make this form work via Ajax, all examples I found on Internet was form that related to node.

So when I tried to apply the same concept, I faced the problem of rendering the form, so I have passed it to the template as a parameter like this:

```
$vars['node']->contactForm = drupal_get_form('nilecode_form');
```

When I render the form by using `drupal_render_children($node->contactForm)`, all the fields were rendered but with no wrapping form tag.

So after frustration, and not very useful IRC chats, I am thinking to do it by using normal Ajax request.

Before doing so is there any solution, before doing it the bad way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my ajax form examples, the best way of achieving this is using a theme function for the form:
http://monchacos.com/monchacos/code/creating-forms-template-file-ajax-included

Theres an attachment in the post, so you can get the full code example.